# Size of arraylist of arraylist

Tags: arraylist

```
public static ArrayList<int []>[] activity=new ArrayList[nbAct];

public static ArrayList<int[]> services;

public ActivityServices(){

 for(int i=0;i<nbAct;i++){
   activity[i]=null;
   for(int j=0;j<nbService;){
        services.add(j,null);`
        int[] qostab=new int[nbQoS];
        for(int q=0;q<nbQoS;q++){
            qostab[q]=valuesServices[q][i][j];
            }
        services.set(j, qostab);
            j++;
    }activity[i]=services;
}
```

I use activity[] to add other services in my class, and I need to use use them after. Knowing that each activity[i] has a different size:
           i.e:
        activity[1] ---> 2 services
        activity[2] ---> 6 services
     I want to it to display 2 for activity [1] and 6 for activity [2] and not number of elements I have = 2+ 2 + 6 =10

Comment: Could you add an example of your inputs?

Comment: You should also add the output you're getting as well as the output you expect. Where are these values being printed?

Answer (score 0):

A few things to note:

- qostab[q] is an array of whatever is contained in valuesServices[q][i][j]
- The value of qostab[q] (which is the value of  valuesServices[q][i][j]) is added to services at index location j
- It looks like there might be a bug with your original code, but from what I can tell, you mean to place services into activity[i]
- services is an ArrayList of int[]. It is not an ArrayList of int. This is probably why you're not getting the expected output.

Corrected(?) code:

```
public ActivityServices(){

 for(int i=0;i<nbAct;i++){
   activity[i]=null;

   for(int j=0;j<nbService;){
        services.add(j,null);`
        int[] qostab=new int[nbQoS];

        for(int q=0;q<nbQoS;q++){
            qostab[q]=valuesServices[q][i][j];
        }
        services.set(j, qostab);
    }
    activity[i]=services;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your time and explications.
My mistake was in creating services outside the loop, which doesn't creat a new "services" at each activity. So when I display the size of activity[i] it gives me the size of services because it's the only one that exists.